# Gaining reputation when a negative question is voted up

Tags: discussion, questions, reputation

Recently, I asked  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26269426/why-and-how-do-uninitialized-char-start-at-52-in-c). about an hour ago, it was rated up from -2 to -1, and I received 5 rep on Stack Overflow. Since the question is now +2/-3, I have actually gained a net 4 rep from asking it, despite it being negative.

Shouldn't the total rep that I have received for the question reflect that the question has a total negative score?

Comment: You made two SO users happy with your question and three of them sad.  Making people happy is just plain harder to do than making them sad so you get more reputation for it.

Comment: related: [Why does reputation start at 1, and have a lower bound of 1?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2621/165773) and [Are the -2's for downvotes on 1-rep users permanently written off?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112757/165773) at MSE

Answer (score 2):

Nope: this is not a bug.

Upvotes are valued more heavily than downvotes (+5/-2 for questions and +10/-2 for answers), so you can gain reputation even from a question whose net score is below zero.

This is done primarily to incentivize good content (== upvotes) through positive reinforcement. In other words, people respond better to upvotes on good questions than they do to downvotes on bad questions, so upvotes are valued more than downvotes.

So, unless you're arguing here that it *should be the other way around* (or that they should be equal), this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Comment: I wasn't talking about upvotes being valued more--just that the actual total doesn't matter.

Comment: @Smurfton The total doesn't matter, for the reasons I said and the one that Hans [pointed out](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274838/gaining-reputation-when-a-negative-question-is-voted-up/274839?noredirect=1#comment107573_274838). I see your point, though.

Answer (score 1):

That's how it works. If 2 people upvote your question it will take 5 people to downvote it before you get back to a net of 0 reputation.

I'm quite certain the net result is that some people gamble with their posts, especially answers. On an answer if you get *one* upvote, it will take 5 downvotes to counter the gain.